# How to format timzone.now() in Django in models.py?

Tags: python, django, django-models, datetime-format

I have a DateField in my models.py, which is set to timezone.now(). How can I change the date format that it is saved in?

I appreciate that I can change it in the template easily enough, but this won't solve my particular problem.

I have tried adding the below into my **settings.py**, but nothing has changed.

```
USE_L1ON = True

DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS =  ('d-m-Y')
```

I would be very grateful for any help here.

Comment: Do you want to change how the date is stored in database?

Comment: Hi Klas, yes exactly

Comment: date != datetime :)

Comment: The database backend will save the data in the most appropriate column/format, usually a specific "date" or "datetime" type column in this case, there is no reason to change it even if it were simple/possible

Comment: Thanks Iain - this makes most sense and have found a workaround!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `%` for it (and your probably should add comma to 1-element tuple). Also, you are trying to store DATE, not DATETIME:

```
DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = ('%d-%m-%Y', )
```

[Django DOCS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#date-input-formats)

Comment: Thanks Nixon, unfortunately when I use the above nothing changes. How can I decide the format that timezone.now() is saved in for a DateField?